# How to set Poltergeist timeout option with Capybara when running against an app_host?

Tags: rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :poltergeist
  config.app_host = 'http://localhost:9292'
end
```

According to Poltergeist [docs](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization), to init Poltergeist with options:

```
options = { timeout:0 }
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

So, I don't have an app to pass to the Poltergeist init. How to set it up without an app?

The following did ***not*** set the option:

```
options = { timeout:0 }
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new( options )
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, this should work:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, timeout: 30)
end
```